# Why do we use two constants in the definition of quasi-isometric embedding?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, isometry, geometric-group-theory

A map $f: X \to Y$ is a quasi-isometric embedding if there exists constants $K \ge 1$ and $C\ge 0$ so that for all $x, x' \in X$ we have
$$\frac{1}{K}d_X(x,x') -C \le d_Y(f(x), f(x')) \le K d_X(x,x') +C.$$

But we could also let $R=\max\{K,C\}$ and the quasi-isometric embedding still holds.

**Why is this not used as the definition?**

Comment: In part, this is because there are special cases when quasi-isometries are particularly nice: when $C=0$ and when $K=1$. Otherwise, you are right, one constant is enough.

Comment: I have to admit that my immediate reaction to this question was to wonder why you might think it was preferable to use one constant rather than two. As Moishe Kohan commented, that makes the definition less precise.

Comment: We can even use 4 constants: $K_1{d_Y}^*f-C_1\le d_Y\le K_2{d_Y}^*f+C_2$. For instance, when we pass to the asymptotic cone, the additive constant disappear while the multiplicative one are preserved.

Comment: The answer is that is not a single way to formulate the definition, but several more or less obviously equivalent formulations. When making quantitative statements it is useful to specify the definition, and talk, for instance, of a $(K,C)$-QI-embedding, and such a specification is sensitive on the precise formulation, and is chosen according to your particular needs.

Comment: I really **HATE** to throw away information. Discarding mathematical information is something I will resist. I will protest if I can no longer formulate statements like: "An isometry is a $(1,0)$ quasi-isometry"; or "A $K$-bilipshitz homeomorphism is a $(K,0)$ quasi-isometry"; or "If $f : X \to Y$ is a $(K,C)$ quasi-isometry, and if $X' < X$ is a net (i.e. each point of $X$ is uniformly close to some point of $X'$), then the restriction $f : X' \to Y$ is a $(K,C')$ quasi-isometry for some $C'$ ".